# Inconsistent results for Integrate depending on irrelevant assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I stumbled across this amusing issue today when doing some definite integrals:

```
integrand[x_] := Sqrt[1 + a (-1 + x)]
Integrate[integrand[x], {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> True]
Integrate[integrand[x], {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> sky == "blue"]
```

which then gives the results

```
(2 (1 - (1 - 2 a)^(3/2)))/(3 a)
```

and

```
ConditionalExpression[(2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 a] + 4 Sqrt[1 - 2 a] a)/( 3 a), 
Re[1/a] == 1 || Re[1/a] >= 2 || Re[1/a] <= 0 || 1/a \[NotElement] Reals) 
&& Re[a] < 1]
```

As you can see, the results appear quite different, even though the input varied only by adding an utterly irrelevant assumption. The latter result is the same as the former, within its limited domain of applicability. But is the former result generally correct?

I'm using Mathematica 9.0.1, if that makes any difference. The above was performed on a freshly restarted kernel.

Comment: looks like perhaps changing the assumptions is impacting the default generateconditions behavior. see what you get if you explicitly set that.

Comment: Are you asking "why this happens?" or "is the former result generally correct?" ?

Comment: What happens when pigs fly? :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 [Then they start playing good music](http://members.tele2.nl/peterhouwelig/mp/Front.JPG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

confirming my comment..

```
   Integrate[ Sqrt[ 1 + a (x - 1) ] , {x, -1, 1}],
   Integrate[ Sqrt[ 1 + a (x - 1) ] , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> True]
   Integrate[ Sqrt[ 1 + a (x - 1) ] , {x, -1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
   Integrate[ Sqrt[ 1 + a (x - 1) ] , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> {y == 3}]
   Integrate[ Sqrt[ 1 + a (x - 1) ] , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> {Re[1/a] != 1}]
   Integrate[ Sqrt[ 1 + a (x - 1) ] , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> {Element[a, Reals]}]
```

[image]

Pretty much any non-default `Assumption` sets `GenerateConditions->True`. (why it defaults to `False` in this case is a fair question)

Looking at another example:

```
Integrate[ 1/(1 - a x) , {x, -1, 1}]
Integrate[ 1/(1 - a x) , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> True]
Integrate[ 1/(1 - a x) , {x, -1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
Integrate[ 1/(1 - a x) , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> {y == 3}]
Integrate[ 1/(1 - a x) , {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> {Element[a, Reals]}]
```

[image]

We see again the superfluous assumption has evidently set `GenerateConditions->True`.
Oddly the default here gives a different conditional expression.

Comment: +1 I've seen `GenerateConditions` default to `False` when there is only one conditional before

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never realised that GenerateConditions defaulted to False - that seems quite dangerous. I suppose it could be because generating conditions is quite slow.